# copying gdi+ bitmap into directx texture

Tags: c++, directx, gdi+

I'm currently attempting to copy a gdi+ bitmap into a directx texture.

I'm using DirectX9 due to Win XP restraints. The following is my code attempt:

```
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdiplus.lib")

void attemptCopy()
{
static IDirect3DTexture9* mTexture;
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput m_gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR m_gdiplusToken;

Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &m_gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

HDC hdc;
PAINTSTRUCT  ps;
UINT mWidth = 1024;
UINT mHeight = 1024;

//hdc = BeginPaint(g_engine->getWindowHandle(), &ps);
using namespace Gdiplus;

Bitmap bitmap(1024, 1024, PixelFormat32bppARGB);
Graphics graphics(&bitmap);

Color transparent = Color(0, 255, 255, 255);
graphics.Clear(transparent);

graphics.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias);
graphics.SetInterpolationMode(InterpolationModeHighQualityBicubic);
graphics.SetTextRenderingHint(TextRenderingHintAntiAlias);

FontFamily fontFamily(L"Arial");
StringFormat strformat;
wchar_t pszbuf[] = L"Text Designer";

GraphicsPath path;
path.AddString(pszbuf, wcslen(pszbuf), &fontFamily, 
    FontStyleRegular, 48, Gdiplus::Point(10,10), &strformat );
Pen pen(Color(234,137,6), 6);
graphics.DrawPath(&pen, &path);
SolidBrush brush(Color(128,0,255));
graphics.FillPath(&brush, &path);

//save bitmap for comparison
CLSID pngClsid;
GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &pngClsid);
bitmap.Save(L"test_bit.png", &pngClsid, NULL);

D3DXCreateTexture(
    g_engine->getDevice(),
    mWidth,
    mHeight,
    1,
    0,
    //D3DFMT_A8L8,
    D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8,
    D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
    &mTexture);

D3DLOCKED_RECT lockedRect;
mTexture->LockRect(0, &lockedRect,0, 0);   

unsigned char* TexData = (unsigned char*)lockedRect.pBits;

memcpy(TexData, &bitmap, sizeof(bitmap) );

mTexture->UnlockRect(0);

D3DXSaveTextureToFileA("test.png",D3DXIFF_PNG, mTexture, 0);

//EndPaint(g_engine->getWindowHandle(), &ps);
Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(m_gdiplusToken);
}
```

Basically I'm trying to attempt a memcpy of the gdiplus bitmap to the directx texture.
The results are the following:

1. `test.png`(the saved directx texture)
   http://i1280.photobucket.com/albums/a500/daegon123/test_zps09f12c7f.png
2. `test_bit.png`(the saved bitmap for comparison)
   http://i1280.photobucket.com/albums/a500/daegon123/test_bit_zpse8be6cd7.png

test_bit.png is returning a proper image, while the directx texture remains blank. Hence, it seems I'm just doing some incorrectly in the copy procedure.

Any ideas on how I could get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
memcpy(TexData, &bitmap, sizeof(bitmap) );   // this is not correct
```

You're copying the `Bitmap` class itself but you should be copying the pixels that it's wrapping. So you need to [lock the bitmap pixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get access to the underlying data.

Something like this:

```
BitmapData bitmapData;
bitmap.LockBits(&Rect(0,0,mWidth,mHeight), ImageLockModeRead, 
    PixelFormat32bppARGB, &bitmapData);
unsigned char *pSourcePixels = (unsigned char*)bitmapData.Scan0;
```

Then you have to copy the pixels row by row in case the stride sizes are different:

```
// get destination pointer and copy pixels
unsigned char *pDestPixels = (unsigned char*)lockedRect.pBits;
for (int y = 0; y < mHeight; ++y)
{
    // copy a row
    memcpy(pDestPixels, pSourcePixels, mWidth * 4);   // 4 bytes per pixel

    // advance row pointers
    pSourcePixels += bitmapData.Stride;
    pDestPixels += lockedRect.Pitch;
}
```

Note that you need to make sure that the underlying pixel formats are equivalent - I've assumed both are the same, but you may need to amend the above code if you need to reorder e.g. BGRA to ARGB etc.